# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

What am I trying to do, is connect my app to third party API through node module.

You can see the code I am using right now below. I am doing a school project and the library I am using for requesting data from API can be found here

This package isnt maintained do not use it
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dota2_web_api

It should show data from that match ID.

But instead I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong with handling promise?

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotaWebAPI = require('dota2-web-api');
const api = new dotaWebAPI("<redacted api token>");

  const matchId = 3574415631
  api.getMatchDetails(matchId)
  .then(data => console.log(data.result));
```

Comment: This error indicates that `api.getMatchDetails` is returning `undefined` somehow. Double check that `getMatchDetails` is returning a promise (or something with the `then` function defined). Check the value of `matchId`, etc.

Comment: The document is incorrect. That function does not return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their docs:

> dota2API.getMatchDetails('3193699040', function(res) {
>      console.log(res);
>   });

so rather than using the Promise syntax try the second parameter callback.